# I have to clear CMOS to Boot

Tags: boot, battery, cmos

The problem I have is that I need to remove the CMOS battery so the computer would turn on. It appears to be dead, I press the power button and it does absolutely nothing, no lights on, no beeping, just as it was dead.

I read or figured out that removing the battery might help, and that is what I did. The problem now is that I have to do it once every four or five times I turn on the computer, and it is becoming really annoying.

The battery is the one that came with the motherboard, so I don't think it could be discharged. And I don't know what else look for, I don't really know what could be causing this.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Any directions or hints that help me diagnose the problem?

Any of those would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could have corrupted BIOS, Bad PSU, or bad MOBO. Try to clear the BIOS and see if that fixes it. Next test with a new PSU. If that doesn't fix it then it may very well be the motherboard.

Comment: @Raystafarian: how do you clear the BIOS if BIOS itself stores settings in the CMOS, hello?

Comment: @XXL [jumper](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS) method. No need to be disrespectful.

Comment: @Raystafarian that is why you clear the CMOS, not the BIOS. There was nothing offensive in my post - I was just pointing out the factual mistake. No need to be so defensive. In fact, if you remove the battery and unplug the PSU - the contents of CMOS will be corrupted and defaults should be loaded (on checksum mismatch).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I must clear my cmos to be able to boot](http://superuser.com/questions/251610/i-must-clear-my-cmos-to-be-able-to-boot)