# Asus X99-Deluxe - Can only boot with the "Clear CMOS" button after cooler installation

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi, cmos

It sounds like I have similar symptoms to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/221394/computer-only-boots-when-cmos-set-to-clear), but this only started happening after swapping out a heatsink for a [cooler](http://www.corsair.com/pt-pt/hydro-series-h110-280mm-extreme-performance-liquid-cpu-cooler).  To be precise, the system will only boot if I press the clear CMOS button.  This resets my UEFI settings, which is annoying since my RAID setting is reset (so my RAID is not recognized).

Outside of that, the motherboard LEDs are lit when power is connected.  The power button just doesn't do anything (on the motherboard).  Paradoxically, if I have booted the computer via "clear CMOS", I can turn it off with the main power button.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Verify all cable connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try updating you bios. Instructions for you specific motherboard can be found [here](http://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1003256/)

Comment: So, that works in the sense that I can restart successfully once the BIOS has been flashed.  However, while troubleshooting my RAID config, the system gets hung up on the boot.  This seemingly unrelated issue (it predated the restart issue) requires a hard kill.  Once that happens, I have to clear CMOS to restart again, reflash BIOS, so on and so forth.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Ramhound I agree

Comment: Actually, I think I ended up flashing the BIOS, which ended up fixing the RAID issue as well.  It turns out the BIOS RAID configuration settings were not available until after the flash.  Everything works now.  This is fortunate because that motherboard is already a replacement!

Comment: @LionBlade123 - The linked page contains no text.  Answers should self-contained, so when a link stops working ( or it acts weird for somebody), the answer can stand by itself.